# MWFeedParser - Parsing For Additional Tags

Tags: ios, xml, ios5

I'm attempting to use MWFeedParser for an application and the Feed that I'm using has an  tag, which is critical for what I'm trying to accomplish. How would I use MWFeedParser to get this data? I've looked in enclosures but it doesn't appear that it is contained there. I'm aware that MWFeedParser says that it only parses for certain tags but I'd have to imagine that there is a way to extend it to parse for something like this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll need to modify either the `MVFeedInfo` or `MWFeedItem` class (depending on whether the tag exists once for the feed or once per item in the feed) to include an extra ivar and @property for the new tag value.  Then in `MWFeedParser.m` you'll need to modify `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName` to set the value of your MVFeedInfo/MVFeedItem property when the `currentPath` is equal to the name of your additional tag.